# MySQL join doesn't return results even when it should

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a seemingly straight forward problem. I'm matching a list of ids with another list of ids in a second table. The following queries execute fine and return a result:

```
select * from dataTable where id = 3888;
select * from moreIDs where mmid = 3888;
```

The join statement, however, returns no results.

```
select * from dataTable inner join moreIDs on dataTable.id = moreIDs.mmID;
```

Any idea why I'm not getting any results from the join?

Comment: What is the data type of these columns are they int or numeric

Comment: Are you sure that any values actually match? Just because each has 3888 doesn't mean they are exact matches....

Comment: both are declared varchar(15)

Comment: KathyA, can you elaborate? I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: Actually, I think I figured it out. I'm not sure why, but when I changed the type of the moreIds' mmID to be an integer, it works. I'm reading the file in from excel. Any ideas what has happened?

Comment: I would guess that you have trailing spaces or extra characters in your varchar.  For instance at http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5100d/1 when I look for id = 3888, it returns both records from dataTable, even though the second record is actually '3888 '

Comment: which MySQL Server version do you use?

Comment: I'm on mysql server version 5.5

Comment: Thanks Brian! I took a closer look at my data files, and it appears you're correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've figured out int the comments, your issue is related with data types.

The following fiddle shows some tests: [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9dba8/1).

First, I've created three tables as the following:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (id varchar(15));
CREATE TABLE table2 (id varchar(15));
CREATE TABLE table3 (id int);
```

And inserted some data:

```
INSERT INTO table1 values ('3888');
INSERT INTO table2 values (' 3888 '); -- extra spaces
INSERT INTO table3 values (3888);
```

If you query a `varchar` column comparing it with an `int` value, the `varchar` will be implicity cast to `int` and extra spaces will be removed. The following examples return `3888`:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = 3888; 
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id = 3888;
```

But if you try this match in a `JOIN` operation, you will be comparing `varchar` with `varchar`, so `'3888' = ' 3888 '` will be evaluated as false.

To solve this, you may convert one of the columns to `int` (so cast will be used) or use the `TRIM()` function, like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON TRIM(table1.id) = TRIM(table2.id);
```

Note: If possible, convert **both** columns to `int` to get a [SARGABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable) query. The cast operation (`varchar` to `int`) in each row will have a performance impact if you use indexes.